# Solving a Weak Interacting Gross-Pitaevskii equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve the Gross-Pitaevskii equation for varying parameters, by creating a function:

```
GPSolverWeakInteraction[m_, \[Omega]x_, \[Omega]y_, \[Omega]z_, 
   asNorm_] := 
  Module[{\[CapitalPsi], mass, Vext, g, hbar, a0, \[Mu]B, \[Omega]ho, 
    as, aho, Solution},
   mass = m;
   a0 = 5.29*10^-11;
   as = asNorm a0;
   hbar = 1.055*10^-34;
   \[Omega]ho = (\[Omega]x \[Omega]y \[Omega]z)^(-1/3);
   aho = (hbar/(mass \[Omega]ho))^(1/2);
   g = (4*\[Pi]*hbar^2*as)/mass;   
   Vext[r_] := 0.5*mass*(\[Omega]ho^2*r^2);
   Solution = 
    NDSolve[{I hbar D[\[CapitalPsi][r, t], 
         t] == -(hbar^2/(2 mass r)) D[r*\[CapitalPsi][r, t], {r, 2}] +
         Vext[r]*\[CapitalPsi][r, t] + 
        g*Abs[\[CapitalPsi][r, t]]^2*\[CapitalPsi][r, 
          t], \[CapitalPsi][aho, t] == \[CapitalPsi][-aho, t], \[CapitalPsi][0, t] == 
       1}, \[CapitalPsi][r, t], {r, -aho, aho}, {t, 1, 10}];
   Return[Solution]];
```

And I get the following error:

```
GPSolverWeakInteraction[2.71375*10^-25, 2 \[Pi]*18.5, 2 \[Pi]*53, 
 2 \[Pi]*81, 100]

NDSolve::bcedge: Boundary condition \[CapitalPsi]$7822[0,t]==1 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.
```

Could someone please help with this? Am I approaching the problem in a completely wrong way?

Comment: It looks like you try to solve spherical symmetric case with `r>=0` while use negative value for `r` as  `{r, -aho, aho}` and periodic boundary condition `\[CapitalPsi][aho, t] == \[CapitalPsi][-aho, t]`. Also there is no initial condition in your code, but second boundary condition   `\[CapitalPsi][0, t] == 1`. It should be something like   `\[CapitalPsi][r,1] == 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding initial condition and `Method`, and taking domain for spherical symmetrical case, we have

```
GPSolverWeakInteraction[m_, \[Omega]x_, \[Omega]y_, \[Omega]z_, 
   asNorm_] := 
  Module[{\[CapitalPsi], mass, Vext, g, hbar, a0, \[Mu]B, \[Omega]ho, 
    as, aho, Solution}, mass = m;
   a0 = 5.29*10^-11;
   as = asNorm a0;
   hbar = 1.055*10^-34;
   \[Omega]ho = (\[Omega]x \[Omega]y \[Omega]z)^(-1/3);
   R0 = aho = (hbar/(mass \[Omega]ho))^(1/2);
   g = (4*\[Pi]*hbar^2*as)/mass;
   Vext[r_] := 0.5*mass*(\[Omega]ho^2*r^2);
   sol = NDSolve[{I hbar D[\[CapitalPsi][r, t], 
         t] == -(hbar^2/(2 mass r)) D[r*\[CapitalPsi][r, t], {r, 2}] +
         Vext[r]*\[CapitalPsi][r, t] + 
        g*Abs[\[CapitalPsi][r, t]]^2*\[CapitalPsi][r, 
          t], \[CapitalPsi][aho, t] == 
       Exp[-5 t], \[CapitalPsi][aho/1000, t] == 
       Exp[-5 t], \[CapitalPsi][r, 0] == 1}, \[CapitalPsi], {r, 
      aho/1000, aho}, {t, 0, 10}, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 81, "MaxPoints" -> 137, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]; 
   f = \[CapitalPsi][r, t] /. sol;
   {f, R0}];


GPSolverWeakInteraction[2.71375*10^-25, 2 \[Pi]*18.5, 2 \[Pi]*53, 
 2 \[Pi]*81, 100]

DensityPlot[Abs[f], {r, R0/1000, R0}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 5},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ClippingStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Figure 1]